How to make a class extend a Realm Class AND add a have a property as of this class as another RealmCLass?
Is it possible to extend a Realm Class inside any other class in Flutter and has a property of a RealmClass field(using has a relationship) inside that class ?
@JsonSerializable()
class Matches extends MatchItem {

  @JsonKey(defaultValue: const [])
  List<String> users = [];

  @JsonKey(defaultValue: const [])
  List<ChatItem> chats = [];

  Matches(super.timeAt, super.uid, super.userId);

  factory Matches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MatchesResFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MatchesResToJson(this);

}

In example above ChatItem and MatchItem both are Realmclasses and Matches class is a response class for fetching Matches from network call.
The Error I am getting is -

[SEVERE] json_serializable on
lib/network/models/GetChatsMatchesRes.dart:
Cannot populate the required constructor argument: timeAt.
package:cupcake/network/models/GetChatsMatchesRes.dart:54:3    ╷ 54 │
Matches(super.timeAt, super.uid, super.userId);    │   ^^^^^^^    ╵


Yes, it is possible - then again, it depends on what's meant by "possible". Without more info though and some example code, not sure we're going to be able to help further. Generally here on SO, asking "is it possible" is considered vague and may get the question closed. Can you provide a code example? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

@Jay Can you please have a relook. Thanks (y)
